# Как передать данные в бинарный поиск из функции сортировки?

Tags: c#, .net

Не понимаю как передать,и как обозначить left и right, и передать значения по аргументу из функции сортировки
`using System;
namespace Sorting
{
    class Programm
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        int[] array = new int[10];
        array[0] = 25;
        array[1] = 15;
        array[2] = 154;
        array[3] = 145;
        array[4] = 19;
        array[5] = 88;
        array[6] = 5;
        array[7] = 45;
        array[8] = 14;
        array[9] = 10;
     var result = Inciment(array);
    }
    public static int[] Inciment(int[] array)
    {
        int t;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                if (array[i] > array[j])
                {
                    t = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = t;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(array[i] + ", ");
        }
        return array;
    }
    public static int BinarySearch(int[] array, var result, int left, int right)
    {
        int left = 0; // Левая граница поиска
        int right = array.Length - 1; // Правая граница поиска
        int index = 0; // индекс, указывающий середину отрезка

        int q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // Запрашиваем искомое число.
        int res = -1; // Конечный результат.

        while (left <= right)
        {
            index = (right + left) / 2; //Узнаем середину отрезка, округляем в меньшую сторону.

            // Если мы нашли искомый элемент, записываем результат и выходим из цикла.
            if (myArr[index] == q)
            {
                res = index;
                break;
            }
            // Меняем границы.
            if (myArr[index] < q)
            {
                left = index + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                right = index - 1;
            }
        }

        if (res != -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Искомый индекс: " + res);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Такого элемента нет в массиве");
        }
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: не понял вашу проблему. Чтобы что то передать в функцию, используйте параметры функции

Answer (score 0):

Не понятна ваша проблема. 
Если проблема в входных параметрах BinarySearch метода, то там left, right не нужны, так как они же инициализируются внутри метода. Если вам нужно не передать их туда, а получить снаружи, инициализировав внутри - перед каждым параметром поставьте out:

```
public static int BinarySearch(int[] array, int[] result, out int left, out int right)
```

var result - работать не будет, нужен тип входящего параметра.